# Flieupload is not working on ascx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

I am facing a problem. I place a control `ascx` at `aspx` page. At aspx page i am using `UpdatePanel`. And at `ascx` page i use a  Formview. In `Formview` `<InsertItemTemplate>` i use a control  `asp:FileUpload`  for File upload. After Selecting file, when i check `FileUpload.HasFile` it gives me false always. I try to fire `<Triggers>` but not
success because file upload is on my `ascx` page. In below example i am showing my problem parts.

```
code 
        FileUpload _fileUpload = FormView1.FindControl("FileUpload1") as FileUpload;
    if (_fileUpload != null && _fileUpload.HasFile)
        {
        /// some code i write here 
        }
```

> ASPX

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" />
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imagAddNew" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="EditProduct1" />
                 <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageButton1" />
            </Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Panel ID="pnl_grid" Style="width: 100%; overflow: auto;" runat="server">
      <uc1:EditProduct ID="EditProduct1" runat="server" />
   </asp:Panel>
```

> ASCX

```
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server"  Width="100%" ondatabinding="FormView1_DataBinding">
  <InsertItemTemplate>
<table>
<tr>
        <td class="label-col">
                   Image
                 </td>
                 <td class="data-col">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                 </td>
<td>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert"
                                ImageUrl="~/images/save.gif" ValidationGroup="Inser" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
  </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FromView>
```

Comment: where is Upload Button for File Uploading

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar in ascx part one image button for file uploading

Comment: i posted an answer try that 100% working

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar where is the answer ? i can't see

Answer (score 0):

try this 100% working

Here Your `FileUpload` Control is Nested Inside the `FormView` so i find that control `ImageButton` and then added `PostBackTrigger` to that control. So you can Apply Same logic to GridView,Repeater,DataList,etc and your can use either `ToolScriptManager`
or `ScriptManager` to Register a PostBackControl

use Image Button like this

```
         <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"
 OnClick="ImageButton1_OnClick" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert"
    ImageUrl="~/images/save.gif" ValidationGroup="Inser" />
```

in Your .aspx page where your are importing user control on page load use this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            FormView ProductsFormView = (FormView)EditProduct1.FindControl("ProductsFormView");

            FindAllTextBoxes(ProductsFormView);


        }
    }



private void FindAllTextBoxes(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton")
            {
                ImageButton ImageButton1 = (ImageButton)c.FindControl("ImageButton1");
                if (ImageButton1 != null)
                {

                    ToolScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(ImageButton1);
//or ScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(ImageButton1);
                }
            }
            if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                FindAllTextBoxes(c);
            }
        }
    }





protected void ImageButton1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ImageButton ImageButton1 = (ImageButton)sender;
        FormViewRow row = (FormViewRow)ImageButton1.Parent.Parent;

        FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)row.FindControl("FileUpload1");

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {

        }



    }
```

if You are using ContentPlace Holder with Master page then

```
ContentPlaceHolder ContentPlaceHolder1 = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
                    ToolkitScriptManager ToolScriptManager1 = (ToolkitScriptManager)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("ToolScriptManager1");
                    ToolScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(ImageButton1);
```

Comment: where it is not working did i test on my machine. any error??

Comment: AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(ImageButton1);

Comment: i add this and error is object reference is required

Comment: my page structure is like this Master Page > aspx page > ascx page here is file uploader

Comment: wrong. use only `ImageButton1_OnClick` code in your user control and place rest of code where your are using user control() in .aspx page

Comment: what u r using `AjaxControlToolkit` or 'ScriptManager'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61417/discussion-between-a-goutam-and-ganesh-devlekar).

Comment: i test on my computer with and without master page its working fine

Comment: can you please send me the example on my id abhishek1bnmu@gmail.com i want to look that. This really stuck me  :( . Tnx waiting for your reply .